# Adding new column and inserting new values in it at the same time using PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Im still new with PHP and Mysql and I have been googling this and have found no answer? I am basically creating a page wherein it everytime you add a training or seminar it will automatically create a new column and insert the values to that created column; I though of this because it i just provide the user 5 columns and they ended up having a new training it would be bothersome if i will create that for them.

I was thinking if it is possible to create a new column after hitting submit and at the same time to save those values from the textbox to the new column created?

Example:

```
textbox: value-a
textbox: value-b
```

Mysql creates two new column and inserts values a and b to the new columns.

If yes, Is it possible to have this column names follow the name of the previous of an existing field?

Example:

```
mysql table

column1 || column2 ||
```

if my question above is possible can it make the field or column name like this having an increment after the name of the field?

```
column1 || column2 || column3 || column4 ||
```

If no? Is there a work around for this or probably an alternate idea to make it easier? I have been trying to figure it out for a while and can find any clue how to do it; All your responses is much appreciated.

Thanks....

Comment: You shouldn't be needing to modify your schema every time a user updates their data. If you're doing that your design is broken and needs revisiting.

Comment: why column instead of a row? a combination of user id and user training is more likely reliable than adding a new column.

Comment: do you know there is a [Maximum Number of Columns Per Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/column-count-limit.html) which can be hit very fast with your approach?

Comment: I see thanks for the reply Mike I agree with what you have said, If that is the case do you have any suggestions or idea in mind?

Comment: Hi Michikot if i understood what you said just add the userid plus training is that correct? sounds like a good plan